# Determine if an optional signature/initial was signed

Tags: docusignapi

When returning tabs for a recipient via the Rest 2.0 API, is there a way to determine if a given optional signature or optional initial tab was actually signed/initialed?

With the required signature/initials, one can easily assume that because the document is complete that they were signed/initialed, but that isn't the case for the optional ones.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a direct way to determine whether or not the signer supplied an initial or signature that was specified as ***optional***.  You might consider this type of work-around:

- Add another type of DocuSign tag to the document(s) that the user is ***required*** to answer/populate -- and that can be used to determine whether or not the signature/initial tag(s) are needed. For example, maybe it's just a Yes/No list or radio button group that the user populates to answer a question like "Opt for extra $50,000 coverage?"
- Use the information that the user supplies in that tag to either hide or show **required** initial/signature tag(s). For example, if the user selected "Yes" to answer the question "Opt for extra $50,000 coverage?" then make the **required** signature/initial tag(s) visible -- otherwise hide them.

Using this approach, you'll be able to programatically evaluate the user-supplied value of the list or radio button tag that controlled visibility of the **required** signature/initial tag(s) in the Envelope.  Using the prior example, if the user selected "Yes" then the **required** signature/initial tag(s) were visible (and therefore had to be supplied prior to envelope completion).  Otherwise, the signature/initial tag(s) were not shown in the Envelope, so they were not supplied by the recipient.